# decrypt hashed passed by md5 function in php to display original password in the edit form

Tags: php, cakephp-3.x

```
$customer->password = md5($this->request->data['password']);
```

Resulted value in database is

```
edd37150ae53ddd72974a8b115a3b78e.
```

but when i call the password in the edit form by 
`echo $this->Form->input('password');`
 it displays password in hashed format. Can you tell me how can i get the original password in the input field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Short answer* : **You can't**.
*Medium answer* : **Even if you could, you shouldn't**.

*Long answer*  :
`Hash` is a one way road where you can't get back the input you hashed. (I won't mention Brute-force)

Apart from that, You **Shouldn't** display old password to your user, no matter what, not even for sake of "forgot password". Its a major security flaw.
If users want to change/reset/edit their password, Just let them have **NEW** password and store that in DB without worrying about old password.

And, another important Note: **Please use [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to hash your password**. `md5` is not designed for password, as It has collision and other serious issue.

Comment: Upvoted for an excellent straight forward response. However, OP seems to be using CakePHP3, you might want to update your answer with a more relevant direction.. Like using Security::hash etc.

Comment: @Karma , in that case I am sorry. I am not familiar with CakePHP. If you have better Idea about it, you are welcome to edit/improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

MD5 by its definition is a one-way hashing algorithm. You can brute-force attack it (which is known to work). But for a web-site and pre-filling the password box with the correct value, there is no viable solution.

My guess is that you want to avoid the user having to type hist password all the time. Or ensuring that the password doesn't get changed when you submit the form.

Options are:

- leave the password field empty - if the form is submitted for let's say a profile change, check for an empty field and leave the password unchanged.
- do not display the password field unless you really want to do a transaction that requires the password again and then have the user type it. Anything else is a breach of security.

Answer (score 0):

here I have a solution that I have implemented in on of my application is to add one more column that just converts the password into an encrypted format by using any hash algorithm like attached and saved in the database.

1 column for original password and second is for edit action.

default_column: password

second column:  encrypt_password

public static function decrypt($string){

```
    $output = false;
    $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
    $secret_key =  'hafizGAmirGWasimG';
    $secret_iv = '@@_hJ%5Xkm48HU7eWem&gbPRm+=qs8bw';
    $key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);
    $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);
    $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($string), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
    return $output;

}

public static function encrypt($string){
    $output = false;
    $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
    $secret_key = 'hafizGAmirGWasimG';
    $secret_iv = '@@_hJ%5Xkm48HU7eWem&gbPRm+=qs8bw';
    $key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);
    $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);
    $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
    return base64_encode($output);
}
```

then when you need to update the password just select that encrypt_password and then decrypt by that function and update and then stored by using that encrypt method as well as update in original password field by md5 method.

also, the best approach is don't show password in the password filed at the time of edit just enter the password if you want to update if not then just leave them empty and then make a if else to updat or not.

if($request->password) then 
update otherwise not.

Comment: Storing plaintext passwords is a TERRIBLE idea. Most people re-use passwords over and over, meaning that if someone manages to hack into your database, there's a very good chance that you're giving them not only the passwords to your site, but to people's email, bank and credit card accounts, iTunes, Amazon, and on and on. Rethink your approach; there are millions of sites that manage to be perfectly user friendly without storing plaintext passwords anywhere.

Comment: bu you can see that i have put a decrypt and encrypt method and it has a password string if it will be true you can got a exact password otherwise not.

Comment: The fact remains that you have a way that a hacker can get someone's combination of email address and actual password. That should *not ever* be possible, under any circumstance.